# AngularJS multidir error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

so I'm stacking on this problem. 
I try to create tabs with loading via ng-include the contents. But doesn't matter what kind of url I include I get always this error http://goo.gl/yyNeQb

I don't have anything else included (Controller,...)

Someone any idea?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'register'}" class="active">
        <a ng-click="main.active.tab = 'register'">Register</a> 
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'login'}">
        <a ng-click="main.active.tab = 'login'">Login</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-switch="main.active.tab">
        <div
            ng-switch-when="register" 
            ng-include src="'../angular/views/register.html'">
        </div>
        <div
            ng-switch-when="login" 
            ng-include src="'../angular/views/login.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- tab content-->
```

If I include a Controller like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angular/controller/RegisterController.js"></script>
```

The source will be load and I can work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tested it immediately but can you try this instead?

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-switch="main.active.tab">
        <div ng-switch-when="register"> 
            <ng-include src="'../angular/views/register.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="login"> 
            <ng-include src="'../angular/views/login.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I set the default tab? So if I open the page that angular use automatically the first tab?

Comment: You can initialize the desired tab name in `main.active.tab` when the page loads, in controller, if you have any. or can just use `ng-init` to initialize the tab name.

Comment: Thanks man! Now I know a bit more about this awesome framework

Comment: Glad that was helpful!. Beware, Angular is an addiction, you can hardly dream of any replacement. ;)